# import information from notepad into sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, import

I'm trying to take bulk data in notepad and use it to insert into a sql database.  I've tried to use Excel but the formatting is off.  Here is what the data looks like.

0312601433: {
    MBSNUMBER: "1041393",
    TITLE: "Writer's Reference",
    AUTHOR: "Hacker, Diana",
    EDITION: "7TH 11",
    BOOKEDITIONSTATUS: "",
    THUMBNAIL: "/TextbookInfo/Thumb/0312601433_t.gif",
    COVER: "/TextbookInfo/Covers/0312601433.gif",
    BOOKPUBLISHER: "MAC HIGHER",
    BOOKSUBPUBLISHER: "BEDFORD BK",
    ALTISBNISBNNUMBER: "31260143",
    ISBN10: "0312601433",
    ISBN13: "9780312601430",
    PRICE_NEW: "80",
    PRICE_USED: "60"
},

0321760166: {
    MBSNUMBER: "1117645",
    TITLE: "Algebra for College Students - With Access",
    AUTHOR: "Lial, Margaret L. / Hornsby, John / McGinnis, Terry",
    EDITION: "7TH 12",
    BOOKEDITIONSTATUS: "",
    THUMBNAIL: "/TextbookInfo/Thumb/M001117645_t.gif",
    COVER: "/TextbookInfo/Covers/M001117645.gif",
    BOOKPUBLISHER: "PEARSON",
    BOOKSUBPUBLISHER: "A-W",
    ALTISBNISBNNUMBER: "32176016",
    ISBN10: "0321760166",
    ISBN13: "9780321760166",
    PRICE_NEW: "219.5",
    PRICE_USED: "164.5"
}

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: That data doesn't look like anything somebody sat down and typed.  How were the text files created?

Comment: pulled from another database using php and outputted on web

Answer (score 0):

You can  use excel to convert it to tabular structure using text to columns feature

for more information [click here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/split-names-by-using-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-HA010102340.aspx)

Comment: It still is looking messed up and would require manual formatting.  This was the method I originally was using when first brining into excel.  I further defined using the information you gave by selecting the column and refining it.  However, the columns don't come out right.

Comment: I was mistaken about what kind of data this is, it is a .json file.  Guess that's why it looks so odd.